# input range add value with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I got a question regarding manipulating the range slider via buttons. I created two buttons which one decrease the value and the other increase the value as can be seen within this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1cmato26/).

But I have some issue with it. As you can see if your press multiple times the less button only the second time the value of my `current_value` variable is updated. What do I do wrong. This also introduce the problem that whenever you pressed the **"less"** button and after that you press the **"more"** button then also the `current_value` is not updated.

This is my JS Code:

```
$('.more, .less').click("on", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  if (current_value == 100 || current_value == 0) {
    return;
  }
  var classname = $(this).attr("class");
  if (classname === "less") {
    $('input').val(current_value-10);
  } else {
    $('input').val(current_value+10);
  }
  $('#result').html("$" + current_value); 
});
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: I've added an answer which allows you to capture when a user drags the slider pointer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of this statemant

```
if(current_value == 100 || current_value == 0){
    return;
  }
```

when you reach `100` or `0` value you will not be able to change the value of input because it will always `return 0`

just try

```js
$('.more, .less').click("on", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  var classname = $(this).attr("class");
  if (classname === "less") {
    if (current_value == 0)
      return;
    else {
      $('input').val(current_value - 10);
      $('#result').html("$" + (current_value - 10));
    }

  } else {
    if (current_value == 100)
      return;
    else {
      $('input').val(current_value + 10);
      $('#result').html("$" + (current_value + 10));
    }

  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 1em">
  <h2>Price</h2>
  <button class="less">
    less
  </button>
  <input id="price" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
  <button class="more">
    more
  </button>
</div>

<p id="result">$50</p>
```

Comment: Awesome exactly what I was looking for. Make more sense also. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try using a click and a change handler to get your slider working properly:

```
$('.more,.less').click(function(){
    var value = parseInt($('#price').val());

    switch($(this).hasClass('more')){
      case true:
        value = value === 100 ? value : value +5;
        break;
      case false:
        value = value === 0 ? value : value -5;
        break;    
    }

    $('#price').val(value).trigger('change');
});

$('#price').change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
    $('#result').html("$" + current_value); 
});
```

Fiddle showing this working: https://jsfiddle.net/1cmato26/3/

Answer (score 1):

it seems to work fine other than the fact that it won't update value once it reaches 0 or 100 because you have a return for both more or less